# How to hide chart legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using `Charts.js` in my app where I am trying to build functionality which allows users to programatically either enable or disable the Legend (it will be either visible or hidden).

I have seen examples how to change chart data by getting the `canvas` object based on ID and then getting `context(2d);` but I could not figure out how to apply new options to it.

Is there a way how to do it?

P.S. I am building a bar chart like following:

under my page I use ng-repeat to build it:

```
<canvas data="{{data}}" id="{{'myChart_' + $index}}" width="1200" height="600""></canvas>
```

Here is the code in my angular app:

```
    $scope.ChartOptions = {
        legend: {
            display:true,
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: [{ display: true }, { labelString: "Test" }],
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: [{ display: true }, { labelString: "Test" }],

            }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        hover: {
            mode: 'single'
        }
    };


            var ctx = $("#myChart_" + index).get(0).getContext("2d");
            var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: data,
                options: $scope.ChartOptions
            });
```

Comment: Which type of chart are you building, if possible provide some code.

Comment: of course, here it goes